# $urlStateProvider undefined error

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have included my dependencies for using Angular UI router but when I run my application I keep receiving an error stating: $urlRouteProvider is not defined. It seems to not be recognizing UI router and is immediately forward to the .otherwise instead of activating the initial login state.

Here is my code:

```
app.js --
var app = angular.module("demoApp", ["ngVidBg", "ngAnimate","ui.router"]);

app.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', function($stateProvider,$urlRouterProvider) {

  $stateProvider
    .state('login', {
      url: '/login',
      templateUrl: 'views/login.html',
      controller: 'LoginCtrl'
    })
    .state('signup', {
      url: '/signup',
      templateUrl: 'views/signup.html',
      controller: 'SignUpCtrl'
    })
    .state('form', {
      url: '/form',
      templateUrl: 'views/form.html',
      resolve: {
        logincheck: checkLoggedin
      }
    })
  $urlRouteProvider.otherwise('/views/login');
}]);

index.html--

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="demoApp">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Demo</title>
        <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/vidBg.css"
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <nav ng-controller="NavCtrl">
           <span ng-show="!currentUser">
           </span>

        </nav>
        <div ng-view>
        </div>
        <!-- jQuery -->
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <!-- Angular -->
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.min.js"></script>


        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.18/angular-ui-router.js"></script>

        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.5/angular-animate.js"></script>

        <script src="./js/app.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="./js/controllers.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="./js/vidBg.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Its typo at the `$urlRouteProvider.otherwise` line, it should be

```
$urlRouterProvider
```

instead of

```
$urlRouteProvider
```

[**$urlRouterProvider Doc**](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing#urlrouterprovider)